# Unclear variables in a struct - Doubly linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef, doubly-linked-list

I'm analysing this bit of code on which I am to build a doubly linked list:

```
struct dplist_node {
  dplist_node_t * prev, * next;
  element_t element;
};

struct dplist {                     
  dplist_node_t * head;
  // more fields will be added later
};
```

In an included header file I found the following lines:

```
typedef int element_t;
typedef struct dplist dplist_t;
typedef struct dplist_node dplist_node_t;
```

What I gather from this is that dplist_node_t is a typedef of the struct dplist_node but there are still pointers defined to dplist_node_t (and thus dplist_node) in both structs.

I find all of this very confusing and can't seem to unravel what is an element of which struct or what pointer is pointing where. Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: With the typedef, `struct dplist` and `dplist_t` are equivalent. That's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this equivalent declaration is easier to understand:

```
struct dplist_node {
  struct dplist_node * prev, * next;
  element_t element;
};

struct dplist {                     
  struct dplist_node * head;
  // more fields will be added later
};
```

the `typedef` adds only confusion in this case.

With:

```
typedef struct dplist dplist_t;
```

you can write `dplist_t` instead of `struct dplist`, or `dplist_t*` instead of `struct dplist*`.

**Illustration**

```
struct dplist_node {
  struct dplist_node * prev, * next;
  element_t element;
};
```

Here it is clear that `prev` and `next` are pointers to the `struct dplist_node` itself.

Original declaration:

```
struct dplist_node {
  dplist_node_t * prev, * next;
  element_t element;
};
```

when we see this, we dont know what `dplist_node_t` is unless we look into the header file where `dplist_node_t` is defined as being the equivalent of `struct dplist`. So IMO it's less clear.

Comment: Alright I think I get it now. But what could be the possible uses of having pointers inside a struct to the struct itself?

Comment: @TheAlPaca02 it's just a declaration. In reality the `next` pointer won't point to the same structure but to another structure. [This link](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html) about linked lists will explain the basics. Otherwise google "C linked list", there are tons of information and tutorials out there.